# Salesforce app stopped authenticate

Tags: authentication, .net

I have C# application which running on daily bases **for the last 18 months**.
The application access SalesForce using 3rd party DLL which I find in GitHub - https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET

Yesterday I saw that the Dll failed authenticate SalesForce.
The error I get is:

> Message   "authentication failure"
>
> Error InvalidGrant    Salesforce.Common.Models.Error

The user is valid - I manage to login with it to the browser as well no change had taken in the secret key/token

This is how I do the connection:

```
        consumerkey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Salesforce_consumerkey"];
        consumersecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Salesforce_consumersecret"];
        username = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Salesforce_user"];
        password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Salesforce_password"];

        AuthenticationClient auth = null;
        Task t = null;

        try
        {
            //create auth client to retrieve token
            auth = new AuthenticationClient();

            //get back URL and token            
            t = auth.UsernamePasswordAsync(consumerkey, consumersecret, username, password);                
            t.Wait();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception("Fail to create SF authentication", e);
        }
```

No idea why now it stopped working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a TLS1.0 issue given the date it happened. The DLL is not able to use tls 1.1 or higher. Here is the tracked [GitHub issue](https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET/issues/262) for the project

**Workaround in issue from avesse**

As far as I know, no. Our workaround is to call the following before calling AuthenticationClient methods:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
```

**Relevant SF Information**

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000221207&type=1

> The September 23, 2017, phase of Salesforce’s planned disablement of TLS 1.0 has been completed. If you are experiencing issues connecting between Salesforce and any integrations, browsers, or other third-party applications, please log a case with Support via the Help & Training portal. If this is a critical production issue affecting all users, please call Support to log a Severity 1 case.
>   A subset of users attempting to login via browsers that are not compliant with TLS 1.1 or higher may not have the ability to log a case through the Help & Training portal. In this event, please call 1-800-NOSOFTWARE to log a case.

Comment: Indeed that solved the case.